# Usage of exact and strict props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working with React-Router in React-JS:

The `<Route>` is an built in component and have two different props:
`exact` and `strict`

**Problem**

The [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/strict-bool) does not clearly defines the differences in between the `exact` and `strict` .

Kindly help me. The document is very confusing and not clear at that point.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

## Use case 1

If you use `exact` and `strict` together, then the `location.pathname` will only match exactly as provided in path props.

Example:

```
<Route exact strict path="/one/" component={About}/>
```

Will only match `/one/` but not `/one` and `/one/two`.

## Use case 2

If you use only `strict`, then the `location.pathname` will match which have trailing slash.

Example:

```
<Route strict path="/one/" component={About}/>
```

Will match `/one/` and `/one/two` but not `/one`.

## Use case 3

If you use only `exact`, then the `location.pathname` will match exact location path.

Example:

```
<Route exact path="/one" component={About}/>
```

Will match `/one` or `/one/`. The `exact` props doesn't care for trailing slash. But it will not match `/one/two`.

Comment: kindly elaborate more. or send me the link of any article

Comment: Got it... your answer really helpful for me.

Comment: Glad, you get it.

Comment: You present the answer in a nice way. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

ReactRouter's `strict` prop defines if there is a **strict** entry of requested path in pathname, as described in docs. For example, if you wish not to handle the page's route without trailing slash, your `Route` can be described like this:

```
<Route path="/mypath/" strict ... />
```

So the pathname `/mypath` won't be handled with this `Route`, and the pathname `/mypath/` will be. Note, that in this mode this `Route` will also catch other child-routes, e.g. `/mypath/childroute`, `/mypath/childroute/childroute2`, etc, but it won't catch route `/mypath?query=...`. Think about this prop like if you are using `"string".includes("substring")`:

```
"/mypath".includes("/mypath/")       => false
"/mypath/".includes("/mypath/")      => true
"/mypath/kappa".includes("/mypath/") => true
```

---

The `exact` prop is used to define if there is an **exactly** the requested path.
Usually it is used to wrap routes without child-routes (e.g. homepage).

```
<Route path="/" exact ... />
<Route path="/" ... />
```

First route will catch only routes like `mydomain.com`, `mydomain.com/`, `mydomain.com/?query=...` etc. The second will catch all routes, e.g. both of `mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com/myroute`.