# React router exact property is not working

Tags: reactjs, path, react-router

The purpose of `exact` property in react router is, don't do partial matching of routes. But, in my case, it is not doing.

I have two component `Write an article` and `View a particular article with id`. I defined route for both as:

```js
<Route exact path='/article/write' exact component={ArticleOrBlog}/>   
<Route exact  path='/article/:id'  component={ArticleOne}></Route>
```

Both route have `exact` property. Expected behaviour is, when `ArticleOrBlog` component render then `ArticleOne` must not, and vice-versa.

## Here the problem concurs.

When `ArticleOne` component renders then `ArticleOrBlog` component is not rendering, but when `ArticleOrBlog` component renders then `ArticleOne` components is also rendering.
`ArticleOne` Component is rendering below `ArticleOrBlog` component.

## Here behaviour changes

When i define routes like:

```js
<Route exact path='/write' exact component={ArticleOrBlog}/>   
<Route exact  path='/article/:id'  component={ArticleOne}></Route>
```

```js
<Route exact path='/write/anything' exact component={ArticleOrBlog}/>   
<Route exact  path='/article/:id'  component={ArticleOne}></Route>
```

then it works fine.

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275146/usage-of-exact-and-strict-props

Comment: Thanks, problem is solved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> when ArticleOrBlog component renders then ArticleOne components is
> also rendering

Reason why `ArticleOne` component also renders is because you have a dynamic param `:id` in the route which matches anything, including `'write'` in `/article/write`.

`exact` prop doesn't stops react router from rendering all the matching routes; it only ensures that only *exactly* matched routes are rendered.

So when the route is `/article/write`, it matches two exact paths:

- `/article/write`
- `/article/:id`

so both components are rendered instead of just one.

When you change routes to `/write` or `/article/:id`, then it works as expected because now `/article/:id` is completely different from `/write`.

**Solution:**

Use `Switch` component that will ensure that only first matched route is rendered.

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/article/write" component={ArticleOrBlog} />
   <Route exact path="/article/:id" component={ArticleOne} />
</Switch>
```

One thing to keep in mind here is that when using `Switch` like shown above, order in which `Route` components are defined - matters.

In your case, `Route` with path `/article/write` *should be defined before* `Route` with path `/article/:id`. This is because if `/article/:id` is defined before `/article/write`, then because of the dynamic param `:id`, `/article/write` will match `/article/:id` path and because of `Switch`, component at `/article/write` path will never be rendered.

Comment: Thanks,, it helps me a lot